# How do I get the value of a dynamic property from firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic4

[image: FXTTC8* is the user ID/property]

I'm building a chat app and I want to add a dynamic field of the user Id where I'll eventually set the user id with the timestamp.

So [uid]: Date.Time

Im not sure how to get this value from firebase.

```js
        qry.get()
        .then((data) => {
          data.forEach(snp => {
              this.travelBuddies.push({
                id: snp.id,
                likes: snp.data().likes,
                userId: snp.data().userId,
                unread: snp.data().unread,
                [this.loggedInUser.uid]: snp.data().?
              });
```

I just want to be able to sort by uid desc.  The last line "[this.loggedInUser.uid]: snp.data().?"  snp.data().name of the user id goes after the dot but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Used [] [this.loggedInUser.uid]: snp.data()[this.loggedInUser.uid],